# Update has caused my system to start in text mode

Tags: 12.04, updates, system

Tonight My system informed me of an update, having preformed the update I was asked to restart the system. Now on start up I'm now presented with the linux console, asking for my user name and password. How do I get back my graphical interface back, when the update left conflicting versions of nVidia Graphics Drivers in place.

I get the error
`ERROR API mismatch Nvidia Kernel is ver 304.48 but the driver component is 295.40`
when attempting to start X from the console.

Comment: Solutions for similar problems might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Answer (score 4):

Your getting to the text console because X won't start. The easiest way to get it working again so you have a UI to work from is to run

`sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /home/username/xorg.conf.backup

sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*
sudo restart`

When you come back up, everything should auto detect fine and you will get a basic GUI.

From that point your going to have to set back up your video card drivers. To do that:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

sudo restart`

When you restart this time you should have a fully working GUI.

Comment: Thanks coteyr I will try this also my system is an ASUS with a i7 the graphics card is a NVIDIA

Comment: Ok, then once your back inside the basic GUI, run "additional hardware drivers", and activate the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Hi That didn't work

Comment: this was OK .. sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /home/username/xorg.conf.backup, the "restart" wouldn't work. I forced a restart but on restarting I get just a blank screen. any ideas !

Comment: Define "blank screen". It's normal for that next boot to take FOREVER. Also do you/can you get to a console again? You likely just need to resetup the drivers. If you can get to a console then it's easy.

Comment: Blank screen is defined as Flashing cursor in the left top corner with the following in the top center of the screen [ok], if I force a shut down on restart I'm presented with the Linux console and can log in but still have to force a shut down, a ctrl+alt+Del from the blank screen will cause a restart to a Linux console

Comment: Ok if you can get to the linux console then lets try a few things. First stop hard resetting (or rebooting) your computer, this will cause damage unless you've already unmounted your root drive. Next understand that ctrl+alt+F1 will always take you to the first VTY (linux console) the same is true for F1 - F11. Ctrl+Alt+F7 is usually the first X session. So you can normally move between the linux console and X by pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 or Ctrl-Alt-F7.  Next lets try to just start X. `sudo X :1` This should give you a blank screen with a X for a mouse (you may not get the mouse this is normal)

Comment: If that works then Ctlr+Alt+F1 back to the linux console and Ctrl+C to kill that X session. If that doesn't work, then you have a larger issue. Is there any output on the command line that might help.

Comment: Also, I need your actual hardware model.

Comment: OK that works and I was able to kill the session.. when you say hardware model are we talking about the graphics card if so its a GTX480

Comment: On running x again it returns an ERROR API mismatch Nvidia Kernel is ver 304.48 but the driver component is 295.40 so its asking to make sure both are the same. I have tried to take this to chat but the system say I only have 1 reputation

Comment: Yeah, it's fine. I will update the question when we can. so now you need to remove all nvidia `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*` restart.

Comment: Done the restart has now gone into the standard ubuntu screen what next!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` then restart. *by stand screen do you mean X (the GUI?"

Comment: yes ............ I presume that I now open a terminal to the string

Comment: Bingo Thats has sorted it I now have both my monitors up and running a big thanks for your help and time best regards